# ng2-datepicker how to change the date from typescript code?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, ng2-datepicker

I am using the ng2-datepicker in my angular app and I want to update the date from the typescript file.

In the html template:

```
<ng2-datepicker [options]="optionsForMenuDate" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" name="selectedDate"></ng2-datepicker>
```

It is binding to a moment object, so I am trying to update it like this (I have included moment in the angular solution):

```
this.selectedDate = this.moment(date);
```

Where date it the js Date object that I want to set the date to. This just sets the component to null though, even this this.selectedDate is not null.

```
console.log(this.selectedDate); // logs a moment object
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I got it working by following way.

The problem with your code is at below line,

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
```

Here, property 'selectedDate' should be of type 'DateModel' and not the moment object.  The DateModel is defined at,

```
import {DateModel} from "ng2-datepicker";
```

And it has a following properties,

```
export declare class DateModel {
    day: string;
    month: string;
    year: string;
    formatted: string;
    momentObj: moment.Moment;
    constructor(obj?: IDateModel);
}
```

Now you need to set **momentObj** and **formatted** properties to get it working.

Here is the sample code,

```
let dateModel:DateModel = new DateModel();
let momentObj = moment('05-11-1986', "MM-DD-YYYY");
dateModel.momentObj = momentObj;
dateModel.formatted = momentObj.format();
this.selectedDate = dateModel;
```

Comment: It is an interesting solution, I will upvote for this and use it for now. I will select  a cleaner solution. I changed your solution to be: dateModel.formatted = momentObj._i; because I found the display to be better like this. If the date selected is in the current month, then the selected date does not display when the datepicker is first opened. Many thanks

Comment: actually, I found dateModel.formatted = momentObj.format("MM-DD-YYYY"); to work best

Answer (score 1):

you can update using **setStartDate** , test.ts file look like this

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DaterangePickerComponent } from 'ng2-daterangepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

 // @ViewChild(DaterangePickerComponent) this line is very important
  @ViewChild(DaterangePickerComponent)
  private picker: DaterangePickerComponent;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(){

    // get previous day for start date
    let startDate = new Date();
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1);

    // get next day for start date
    let endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);

    this.picker.datePicker.setStartDate(startDate);
    this.picker.datePicker.setEndDate(endDate);

  }

}
```

and html look like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control2"  name="daterangeInput" daterangepicker [options]="options" />
```